# How to get username of linkedIn account

Tags: linkedin-api

I've implemented a singin operation with LinkedIn through Oauth2 protocol and receiving response informations about profile as shown :

```
{
"localizedLastName": "xxxxxxx",
"profilePicture": {
    "displayImage": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
"firstName": {
    "localized": {
        "fr_FR": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
   "id": "xxxxxxxx",
    ....
 }
```

But in my use case i need to store a unique username and i think that i can retrieve it only from **profile link**  https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-889031a0/ 
so how to get this profile link ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `vanityName` of the [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api), from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile):

> vanityName: The vanity name of the member. Vanity name is represented
> as a string is used for the public profile URL:
> `www.linkedin.com/in/{vanityName}`.

So you could use the following curl with the projection on the requested field:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>" \
"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(localizedFirstName,vanityName)"
```

will return:

```
{
  "vanityName": "bsmith",
  "localizedFirstName": "Bob"
}
```

**App Permission**

Double check your app have have the at least the `basicprofile` permission  (OAuth 2.0 scopes): the default `lite-profile` is not enough. So see in the App scope console `https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<app-id>/auth` you should have at least:

> r_basicprofile: Use your basic profile including your name, photo,
> headline, and public profile URL

Comment: sorry it returns only "localizedFirstName"

Comment: Hi @barsawi13  probably is due to a missing scope permission (I've updated my answer)

Comment: i m using LinkedIn Api V2 with scope **r_liteprofile**  and it doesn't have **r_basicprofile** scope as Api V1 has been deprecated since May 2019