# How to get Linkedin username of a person after Oauth V2?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

So, after signin in through Linkedin Oauth, it returns you this or in their words the r_liteprofile :

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "xxxxx",
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:xxxxxx"
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "xxxxx"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "xxxxx"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "localizedFirstName": "xxxx"
}
```

As you can see it does not return the username, but we need it for our use case. Is there any solution or workaround to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get username of linkedIn account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367384/how-to-get-username-of-linkedin-account)